# Creación de elementos Dinámicamente

Tags: jquery

Estoy cargando elementos dinámicamente desde la base de datos, en teoría es algo sencillo con la excepción de que algunos elementos pertenecen a grupos y cuando es así quiero que los cree dentro del grupo correspondiente.

Mi código:

```
        var cantidad = e.length;
        var contador = 1;

        for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
        {

            if(e[i]['groupName'] == null)
            {
                var td1 = "<div id='" + e[i]['taskId'] + "' class='taskRecipient ui-widget-content ui-state-default' data-task='" + e[i]['taskId'] + "'>";

                var subtarea = e[i]['estadoSubtarea'].split(',');  
                var completa = 0;

                $.each(subtarea, function(index, element){
                    if(element == 1)
                    {
                        completa++;
                    }
                });

                var porcentaje = completa * 100 / (subtarea.length -1);
                porcentaje = porcentaje + '%';

                if(e[i]['priority'] == 0 || e[i]['priority'] == null || e[i]['priority'] == undefined)
                {
                    var td2 = "<div class='progressBar' style='width:" + porcentaje + "'></div><div class='title'>" + e[i]['title'] + "</div>";
                }else{
                    var td2 = "<div class='ribbon'></div><div class='progressBar' style='width:" + porcentaje + "'></div><div class='title'>" + e[i]['title'] + "</div>";
                }

                if(e[i]['image'] == "" || e[i]['image'] == null || e[i]['image'] == undefined)
                {
                    var td3 = "<div class='taskicon'>";
                }else{
                    var td3 = "<div class=''><img class='task-img' src='" + e[i]['image'] + "' /></div><div class='taskicon'>";
                }

                if(e[i]['adjunto'] == " " || e[i]['adjunto'] == null || e[i]['adjunto'] == undefined)
                {
                    var td4 = "";
                }else{
                    var adjunto = e[i]['adjunto'].split(',');

                    var td4 = "<i class='si si-paper-clip taskIcon'><div class='task-not'>" + (adjunto.length) + "</div></i>";
                }

                if(e[i]['comentario'] == " " || e[i]['comentario'] == null || e[i]['comentario'] == undefined)
                {
                    var td5 = "";
                }else{
                    var comentario = e[i]['comentario'].split(',');
                    var td5 = "<i class='si si-bubble taskIcon'><div class='task-not'>" + (comentario.length) + "</div></i>";
                }

                if(e[i]['imagenParticipante'] == " " || e[i]['imagenParticipante'] == null || e[i]['imagenParticipante'] == undefined)
                {
                    var td6 = "";
                }else{
                    var participantes = e[i]['imagenParticipante'].split(',');

                    var td6 = "<i class='si si-users taskIcon'><div class='task-not'>" + (participantes.length -1) + "</div></i>";
                }

                if(e[i]['subtarea'] == " " || e[i]['subtarea'] == null || e[i]['subtarea'] == undefined)
                {   
                    var td7 = "";
                }else{
                    var subtarea = e[i]['subtarea'].split(',');
                    var td7 = "<i class='icon-list taskIcon'><div class='task-not'>" + subtarea.length + "</div></i>";
                }

                var cierre = "</div></div>";

                if(e[i]['parent'] == "")
                {
                    if(contador == 1)
                    {
                        $('#capaTask .primero').append(td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+cierre);
                    }

                    if(contador == 2)
                    {
                        $('#capaTask .segundo').append(td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+cierre);
                    }

                    if(contador == 3)
                    {
                        $('#capaTask .tercero').append(td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+cierre);
                    }

                    if(contador == 4)
                    {
                        $('#capaTask .cuarto').append(td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+cierre);
                    }
                    contador++;

                    if(contador == 5)
                    {
                        contador = 1;
                    }
                }else{

                    $(e[i]['parent']).append(td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+cierre);
                }
            }else{



                var taskGroup = "<div class='taskGroup ui-widget-content ui-state-default' data-groupId='" + e[i]['groupId'] + "'><input type='text' class='taskGroupTitleInput' Placeholder='Nombre de Grupo' style='display:none'/><span class='taskGroupTitle' style='display:inline-block'>" + e[i]['groupName'] + "</span>";

                var td1 = "<div id='" + e[i]['taskId'] + "' class='taskRecipient ui-widget-content ui-state-default' data-task='" + e[i]['taskId'] + "'>";

                var subtarea = e[i]['estadoSubtarea'].split(',');  
                var completa = 0;

                $.each(subtarea, function(index, element){
                    if(element == 1)
                    {
                        completa++;
                    }
                });

                var porcentaje = completa * 100 / (subtarea.length -1);
                porcentaje = porcentaje + '%';

                if(e[i]['priority'] == 0 || e[i]['priority'] == null || e[i]['priority'] == undefined)
                {
                    var td2 = "<div class='progressBar' style='width:" + porcentaje + "'></div><div class='title'>" + e[i]['title'] + "</div>";
                }else{
                    var td2 = "<div class='ribbon'></div><div class='progressBar' style='width:" + porcentaje + "'></div><div class='title'>" + e[i]['title'] + "</div>";
                }

                if(e[i]['image'] == "" || e[i]['image'] == null || e[i]['image'] == undefined)
                {
                    var td3 = "<div class='taskicon'>";
                }else{
                    var td3 = "<div class=''><img class='task-img' src='" + e[i]['image'] + "' /></div><div class='taskicon'>";
                }

                if(e[i]['adjunto'] == " " || e[i]['adjunto'] == null || e[i]['adjunto'] == undefined)
                {
                    var td4 = "";
                }else{
                    var adjunto = e[i]['adjunto'].split(',');

                    var td4 = "<i class='si si-paper-clip taskIcon'><div class='task-not'>" + (adjunto.length) + "</div></i>";
                }

                if(e[i]['comentario'] == " " || e[i]['comentario'] == null || e[i]['comentario'] == undefined)
                {
                    var td5 = "";
                }else{
                    var comentario = e[i]['comentario'].split(',');
                    var td5 = "<i class='si si-bubble taskIcon'><div class='task-not'>" + (comentario.length) + "</div></i>";
                }

                if(e[i]['imagenParticipante'] == " " || e[i]['imagenParticipante'] == null || e[i]['imagenParticipante'] == undefined)
                {
                    var td6 = "";
                }else{
                    var participantes = e[i]['imagenParticipante'].split(',');

                    var td6 = "<i class='si si-users taskIcon'><div class='task-not'>" + (participantes.length -1) + "</div></i>";
                }

                if(e[i]['subtarea'] == " " || e[i]['subtarea'] == null || e[i]['subtarea'] == undefined)
                {   
                    var td7 = "";
                }else{
                    var subtarea = e[i]['subtarea'].split(',');
                    var td7 = "<i class='icon-list taskIcon'><div class='task-not'>" + subtarea.length + "</div></i>";
                }

                var cierre = "</div></div></div>";
                var cierre2 = "</div></div>";

                if( $('.taskGroup').is(':visible') && $('.taskGroup').data('groupId') == e[i]['groupId'])
                {
                    alert("el grupo existe");
                }else{
                    $(e[i]['parent']).append(taskGroup+td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+cierre);
                }

            }
        }
```

No soy capaz de que el alert("el grupo existe") salte

Comment: Puedes probar a debuggear con Chrome, a ver hasta donde llega y hasta donde no. Usa la etiqueta debbug; donde quieras que se pare en el código, y despues en el chrome click derecho, "inspeccionar", y luego en el aprtado sources. Si no te va a la primera, teniendo el inspector abierto te debería salir en la parte derecha una barra y en un punto pondrá breakpoints, asegurate que esta el que has puesto en el código, y dale F5

Comment: Por favor, añade código HTML para que así podamos probar el código fácilmente.

Comment: El HTML se genera dinámicamente con el jquery. viene en el código que puse al principio pero dime que quieres ver y te muestro lo que necesites

Answer (score 1):

La solución está en que el if deberia ser:

```
                if( $(".taskGroup[data-groupId = " + e[i]['groupId'] + " ]" ).length )
                {

                    var td1 = "<div id='" + e[i]['taskId'] + "' class='taskRecipient taskGroupElement ui-widget-content ui-state-default' data-task='" + e[i]['taskId'] + "'>";
                    //console.log("el grupo existe");
                    $(".taskGroup[data-groupId = " + e[i]['groupId'] + " ]" ).append(td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+cierre2);

                }else{
                    $(e[i]['parent']).append(taskGroup+td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7+cierre);
                }
```

Con esto criba perfectamente y monta los grupos bien